# Snow Leopard Server MySQL Service and MacPorts MySQL Install Troubles

Tags: mysql, macports, osx-server

Trying to back out of a macports mysql installation and return to Snow Leopard Server's built-in MySQL server, but I cannot get it to work.

When I disable macports and enable the built-in service, `mysql.sock` cannot be found (locate mysql.sock returns nothing). When I re-enable the macport mysql, mysql.sock is found but now I cannot disable the built-in MySQL service.

Every time I try, it just re-enables it.

I have to run the following commands to get MacPorts MySQL to work upon reboots:

```sh
sudo launchctl unload -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.macports.mysql5.plist
sudo launchctl load -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.macports.mysql5.plist
ln -s /var/mysql/mysql.sock /tmp/mysql.sock
```

Permissions on /var/mysql are (which is where the built-in service is set to):

```
drwxr-xr-x   111   _mysql   _mysql
```

Permissions on the macports datadir are:

```
drwxr-xr-x   116   _mysql   _mysql
```

At one time, according to the access log file for the built-in mysql, it started up correctly (2010). Is there a way to manually disable this service from starting up when I reboot?

I realize how unclear my problem is, but somehow the previous admin got macports mysql tied in with the built-in mysql and I'm having a heck of a time untangling them.

Answer (score 0):

In `/Library/LaunchDaemons/` `plist`-files of the installed applications are located, here's what I have there:

```sh
$ ls -l /Library/LaunchDaemons/
-r--r--r-- 1 root wheel 573 Jan 10 18:33 at.obdev.littlesnitchd.plist
-rw-r--r-- 1 root wheel 567 Mar  5 19:02 com.parallels.desktop.launchdaemon.plist
lrwxr-xr-x 1 root admin  74 Jan 20 06:21 org.macports.mysql5.plist -> /opt/local/etc/LaunchDaemons/org.macports.mysql5/org.macports.mysql5.plist
lrwxr-xr-x 1 root admin  74 Oct 14  2011 org.macports.rsyncd.plist -> /opt/local/etc/LaunchDaemons/org.macports.rsyncd/org.macports.rsyncd.plist
```

And if you'd like to check the MacOS bundled services' config, take a look at `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/`.